# Hadoop Datanode Xcievers Error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have built a storage system using HDFS API. I am now running some performance test on to the system. I created a large number of concurrent file retrieving requests through [SIEGE](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) (for example: `siege -c 500 -r 1 "http://bucket1.s3.bigdatapro.org/1.jpg"`). However, I encountered the following problems on datanodes as such:

```
013-06-17 21:08:56,987 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(146.169.35.109:50010, storageID=DS-1983611132-146.169.35.109-50010-1350751070203, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiver
java.io.IOException: xceiverCount 4097 exceeds the limit of concurrent xcievers 4096
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:156)
```

I have already setup this:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
<value>4096</value>
</property>
```

Shall I increase this to a higher value? Is there any side-effect setting this to really high value? like 10000000? 
I have also increated maximum open files to 50000. Am I still missing something? Or have I done something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You opened up a file descriptor leak, do you close your `FileSystem` calls? Or what kind of "HDFS API" are you using?

Comment: Agree with TJ.. You can't just keep on increasing xceivers value, IMHO. See this to know how it works : http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/hbase-hadoop-xceivers/

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Hi Thomas, I am using CDH3 HDFS API. For the stream I have done   os.flush(); and  os.close(); what else shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the xcievers count further based on how many threads your application needs in concurrent. In my research, I have found that the more you put is proved to be bad as we have got hit by performance in big time.

Also in your Datanodes, check the ulimit count if it's creating any issue.